# BrightStor ARCServe Backup job settings not applying

Tags: backup

[image]

I have an backup job that I want to set a file exclusion on. The problem I'm having is that every time I add a filter (e.g. *.log), the setting drops off as soon as I close the job. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found out that I should have clicked the "Start Job" button to apply the changes.